# $Tx=(\lambda_k x_k)_{k=1}^\infty.$ Well defined, bounded and compact.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, compactness

> Fix a sequence of real numbers $(\lambda_k )_{k=1}^\infty$, and define the linear operator $T: \ell_2 \to \ell_2$ by $$Tx=(\lambda_k x_k)_{k=1}^\infty.$$ For what multiplier sequences $(\lambda_k)$ is the operator $T$
>
> - well defined?
> - bounded?
> - compact?

In general if the sequence $(\lambda_k)$ is not bounded, then our linear operator $T$ is not bounded. Assume $(\lambda_k)$ is bounded. Then
$$\left\| Tx \right\|^2 = 
\left\|\sum_{k=1}^\infty \lambda_k x_k \right\|^2 \leq 
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left\|\lambda_k \right\|^2 \left\|x_k\right\|^2 \leq 
\left\|\lambda \right\|^2 \left\|x\right\|^2$$ and so the linear operator is bounded with $\left\|T\right\|=\left\|\lambda \right\|_{l_2}$.

For compactness,
$$\left\| Tx-T_n x \right\|^2= \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \left\|\lambda_k \right\|^2 \left\|x\right\|^2$$ and so
$$\left\| T-T_n  \right\| \leq \sqrt{\left \|{\lambda_k} \right\|^2} \to 0$$ iff $\lambda_k \to 0$.

Are my arguments clear enough for boundedness and compactness? In any case, are my solutions getting close to what the task asks?

Comment: You did not tackle well-definedness. Also, your argument for bounded-ness should not use $\|\lambda\|_{\ell_2}$. Even if $\lambda_k$ are bounded, $\|\lambda\|_{\ell_2}$ may not exist; instead use a bound on $\lambda_k$.

Answer (score 2):

The operator is well-defined and bounded if and only if the sequence $(\lambda_k)$ is bounded. Clearly if it is bounded with bound $M$ then for a sequence $x$ we have $||Tx|| \leq M ||x ||$ so it is well-defined and bounded.

If $(\lambda_k)$ is not bounded, then for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ there is a $k_n$ such that $\lambda_{k_n} > n$. Note that we can choose the $k_n$ to be increasing. Let $x$ be the sequence that is $1/n$ at $k_n$ and $0$ elsewhere. Clearly, $x \in l_2$. However, $Tx \notin l_2$.

I don't know about compact though.