# Why is the sequence bounded in complex number?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

I have the next problem.

Given a sequence $\{\alpha_n\}_{n\in \mathbb N} \subset \mathbb C$ and an operator
$$A:\ell_2\to \ell_2$$ defined by
$A(x_n)=(\alpha_n x_n)$. To show that $A$ is well defined as linear operator bounded from $\ell_2$ in $\ell_2$ if and only if the sequence $\{\alpha_n\}$ is bounded.

I tried the following:

$\rightarrow)$ Let us suppose that $A$ is linear and bounded operator, hence for all $(x_n)\in \ell_2$ we have that
$||A(x_n)||\leq ||A||||x_n||_{\ell_2}<\infty$ then
The series $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}|\alpha_nx_n|^2<\infty$. This implies that
the general term is bounded and $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}|\alpha_n x_n|^{2}=0$. Equivalently
by definition of limit we have that
$\forall \epsilon>0$ there is $N_\epsilon$ integer such that $|\alpha_n x_n|^2<\epsilon$ for all $n\geq N_\epsilon$. In particular for $\epsilon=1$
$$|\alpha_n x_n|^2<1$$
I believe that as my number are less than $1$ and are positives, then
$0\leq|\alpha_nx_n|^2\leq|\alpha_nx_n|<1$ the other side i know too that the series $\sum_{n=1}|x_n|^2<\infty$ so by the same argument $|x_n|<1$ for $n>N_1$ then my number $|\alpha_n|$ has to need be smaller than $1$ but i no know how to prove, or how i can finish my statement. Please if somebody  can helpme to finish i will appreciate so much. Thank you

Comment: You have a series that depends on $x_n$, so you can play around with $x_n$. In particular, you have shown that $\sum |a_n x_n|^2 < \infty$ so that $|a_n x_n|$ is bounded _for any sequence $(x_n) \in \ell_2$. Then you can choose the sequence $x_n$ nicely to get what you want

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3947232/tx-lambda-k-x-k-k-1-infty-well-defined-bounded-and-compact?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making it too complicated. From $\|Ax\|\leq\|A\|\,\|x\|$ evaluating on the $k^{\rm th}$ element $e_k$ of the canonical basis you have
$$
|\alpha_k|=\|Ae_k\|\leq\|A\|\,\|e_k\|_2=\|A\|. 
$$

Comment: Thank you @Martin Argerami